# Are there any alternatives to ASIC chips?

Tags: embedded, asic, performance, alternatives

Are there any other mixed-signal integrated circuit embedded systems (or alternative solutions) which are faster than ASIC in terms of performance (let say for a high-efficiency Bitcoin miner)?

Comment: an ASIC is a chip optimized for a certain task... so no.

Comment: FPGAs may be faster than an ASIC made with an inferior semiconductor process- you may not be able to afford masks for a 28nm ASIC process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is faster than ASIC yet as name suggest it is application specific means it is designed to do only one task, if task increases efficiency will decrease.

Fastest thing that we have now is quantum computer but it will not work for mining bitcoin. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/what-is-more-effective-than-asic-mining